# Send Text Message real time via REST API

Tags: dynamic, text

I am looking for an ability to send dynamic content to real time text message.

Basically i am interested in storing a template of Text Message (like 
"Dear %%customer_name%%") in ET and in my real time REST call i will use this template and pass customer_name=jhony along with other required fields to send the text message.

Can any one help me achieve this.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Twilio’s SMS capabilities. Twilio provides a very good [helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/salesforce/install) to do SMS integration. Here are couple of links you can go through. Hope this helps.

https://twilio-salesforce.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/messages.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339900/unable-to-receive-the-sms-via-twilio